# Spring Boot creating but not writing to Log file (Spring 2.7.2)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, logging

I'm deploying my spring application as a war file on external tomcat.
In the controller class I'm trying to write some log messages to the log file if I visit /applogging

Controller class

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.yaddayadda

@RestController
public class Controller {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Controller.class);
    
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String helloWorld()
    {
        return("Hello World!");
    }

    @GetMapping("/applogging")
    public String doLogs() 
    {
        logger.error("Error message");
        logger.warn("Warning message");
        logger.info("Info message");
        logger.debug("Debug message");
        logger.trace("Trace message");
        return("Logging");
    }
}
```

Main application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringappApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringappApplication.class);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringappApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true
logging.level.root = TRACE
logging.file.name=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.70/logs/webapplogs/springapp.log
logging.pattern.file= %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%
logging.level.org.springframework.web=TRACE
logging.level.org.hibernate=TRACE
```

The log is created in a designated location, but none of the messages are getting written to the log file.
am  I using the wrong properties, or am I doing something wrong in the controller class?

Comment: WIthout calling the endpoint nothing will get written.

Comment: @M.Deinum
could you elaborate some more? how would I call the endpoint?

Comment: You have a controller, with logging in a request handling method. As long as you aren't going to call that method (invoking a request through your browser or curl or http or wget or whatever you use) nothing will be logged as nothing is being invoked.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @M.Deinum's comment...

Logging is initialized before the `ApplicationContext` is created. Read more [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html). So, file appenders are initialized and related files are created before your controller class is instantiated. In other words, logging initialization is independent of your usage of a logger in your controller. This is why the log file is created.

Comment: I know that the logs that output all the autoconfiguration info typically seen in console will be created and written to upon loading (but still before ApplicationContext is created),  so what can I do in my project if I wanted to write to those same log files or even a different log file AFTER the ApplicationContext is created using slf4j? Or is it not possible?

Comment: Just use a logger. I feel like I am missing something.